# Getting Error in running app after update android studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I update the android studio 3.1 i know this is [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553021/program-type-already-present-android-support-v13-view-draganddroppermissionscom) but i don't know how to fix it please help me

**Error:-**

> Program type already present:
>   android.support.v13.view.DragAndDropPermissionsCompat
>       Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v13.view.DragAndDropPermissionsCompat,
>   sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'

        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(app:module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.fiskurgit:ChipCloud:3.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    compile 'co.infinum:materialdatetimepicker-support:3.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.michaelye.easydialog:easydialog:1.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
}
```

Comment: Hi guys, another possible solution related to this error:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51049986/3033184