# Error implementing Material Design in Android

Tags: android, material-design

I've been reading over the new material design website but I'm having an issue implementing it.

The application I'm currently working in is a simple test applications with nothing more than a button and some textviews.

The problem comes after placing `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'` in the gradle file.

heres my build.gradle(app) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.firebasemessagingtest"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've got 4  errors,

```
error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

I have included the maven in the project gradle file like stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

change **`compileSdkVersion`** and Support Libraries version

```
compileSdkVersion  'android-P'
Support Libraries to '28.0.0-alpha1'
```

and use

```
 api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

**EDIT**

> Update your SDK Platform update - Android P Preview (latest)
>
> and also make `targetSdkVersion 'P'`

Than **`Clean-Re_Build-Run`** your project

### EDIT 2

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion  'android-P'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nilesh.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:15.0.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This did help somewhat although it just started throwing other errors. I've tried following the answer posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289355/google-material-design-library-error-program-type-already-present-android-suppo) but still no go.

Comment: Still getting an error - "Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel"

Comment: Adding `android.useAndroidX = true android.enableJetifier = false` to the gradle.properties has solved the build error but when I tried to run it on my mobile it gets errors again.

Comment: @Demonic218 check my edit2 its working fine in android studio

Comment: Sorry Dude, still no go. In my SDK manager Android P Preview says partially installed, if I open it up Android SDK Platform P is the only one installed, is this alright or do they all need to be downloaded ?

Comment: @Demonic218 yes Please update  SDK Platform  to  Android P Preview (latest)

Comment: I've now got everything under the Android P sdk downloaded and installed and I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set `compileSdkVersion` as `'android-P'`.
Match the support library with the `compileSdkVersion`. For instance, `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'` instead of `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`.

Replace `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'` with `api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'`.

The app `build.gradle` should look something like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wolfrevokcats.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 16
        versionName "2.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation ('com.someone.addons:library:1.6.1@aar'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

As `'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'` is being used, our code will have to change to `android.support.design` instead of `com.google.android.material` libraries. Here's an example using the new Bottom App Bar widget.

```
<android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabAttached="true"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"/>
```

Comment: This is actually the route I've decided to go as the tutorial on Material.io website uses support:design instead of the android.material. Could you tell me what the difference is between the two though ?

Comment: Google is rolling out a new package structure to distinguish what is and isn't bundled with the Android Operating System. Those that aren't will be **issued under the new androidx.* package hiearchy**. Read more about [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn)

Comment: `com.android.support:design` will be replaced by the `com.google.android.material:material:xxx` library as shown on the [AndroidX refactoring](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor) page.

Comment: The android.support.* versions will cease after the 28.0.0 releases.

Comment: So wouldn't implementing the android.support.design now be a waste of time seeing as it's going to be replaced ?