# Android Studio Error android.support.v4.app.NotificationSideChannel$tub$Proxy

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

Im trying to create Onboarding screen in Android Studio. When i run i have this Error: ( My SDK version is 28, ANdroid Studio is 3.1.2. I got this problem when come to the new version).

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

My project is compile with SDK version 28. Use appcompact-v7:28.0.0.alpha1..

My code for Adapter is like this:

```
public class Slide_adapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context context;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public Slide_adapter(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }


        //Array

        public int[] slide_image = {
                R.drawable.group10,
                R.drawable.group11,
                R.drawable.group12
        };

        public String[] slide_heading ={
                "INFORMATION",
                "HELP",
                "WARNING"
        };

        public String[] slide_paragraph = {
                "ABC",
                "ABC",
                "ABC"
        };


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return slide_heading.length


                    ;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
            return view == (RelativeLayout) object;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide,container,false);

            ImageView slideImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_images);
            TextView slideTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_heading);
            TextView slideParagraph = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_p);

            slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_image[position]);
            slideTxtView.setText(slide_heading[position]);
            slideParagraph.setText(slide_paragraph[position]);

            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
            container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);

        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301692/3395198

Comment: No help. I got this after follow the answer: 
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
 at