# "Program type already present" when building a Gradle project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-glide

When I ran the build in the android studio, the following error occurred :

`Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel`

These are the dependencies I used :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hex.encode"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.4'
// First I tried building with this, but the same problem with a different library error occurred

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
//Then I tried adding glide, but the same problem occured

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
}
```

The app didn't compile and gave the following error :

```
Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
```

I saw the Google documents but it didn't help much.
Is there any real solution to this.

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301692/8553954

Comment: @meditat yes i tried, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: go and check[ this ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289355/google-material-design-library-error-program-type-already-present-android-suppo) , they mention this problem here before