# MapView with Material Components

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, material-components-android

I was trying to use Material Components in Android Studio. This is how my Gradle looks like now:

```
1) implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
2) implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
3) implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
4) implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Unfortunately, I got this error:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

When I remove the line 3 of my Gradle (*com.android.support:design*), I got this error:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

This happen when I'm using the line 2 of my Gradle (*com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps*), but when I remove it's everything without any errors.

> **Edit**: I guess is not exacly same version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289355), but
>   similar. Not the same 'cause this happens with me only when I'm using
>   the implementation 2), and the fixes offered in the other article
>   aren't solving my problem

Comment: Same version & duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289355/google-material-design-library-error-program-type-already-present-android-suppo Right?

Comment: Hello @ʍѳђઽ૯ท. Maybe not exacly same version, but similar. Not the same 'cause this happens with me only when I'm using the implementation 2), and the fixes offered in the other article aren't solving my problem.