# androidx.mediarouter complains about MediaBrowserCompat

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

Running Android Studio 3.2 RC3. Tried upgrading an old project to use `androidx`. Got most of it working, but I keep getting the error below.

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while
>   generating the main dex list. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while
>   generating the main dex list. 
>   com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException:
>   com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already
>   present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CallbackHandler
>   com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already
>   present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CallbackHandler

I have these properties set in `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
# Tried both false and true...
android.enableJetifier=false
```

The following line in my `app.gradle` seems to be the culprit:

```
implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.0.0'
```

Obviously, I need the classes from that library so I can't remove it.

### Update

External libraries shows this suspicious dependency:

```
Gradle: androidx.media:media-1.0.0
  classes.jar
    android.support.v4.media
      MediaBrowserCompat
      MediaBrowserCompatApi21
      MediaBrowserCompatApi23
      MediaBrowserCompatApi26
```

**Why this dependency?**

Comment: `Error while generating the main dex list` Is multidex enabled ?

Comment: Yes. I tried to disable it, but no difference for this particular class.

Comment: Can we see your `Build.gradle`? Please edit the question and paste the contents of it in the question.

Comment: I don't think the gradle will help in this case (tried creating a minimum project using the same settings, but it works). Most puzzling is that "Rebuild All" works, but then if I choose "Make Project" it gives me this error. Even if I turn off multi-dexing.

Comment: I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52560036/6570945). Hope it works for you.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?  I have the same error.

Comment: I think the error disappeared after updating all dependencies that referenced some old version of the Support Library.