# Program type already present after updating from sdk 27 to 28

Tags: java, android

After I changed my sdk from 27 to 28 and changed some of the dependencies in my gradle to overcome the problem of **manifest merger** I faced the error of

Program type already present:android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Here is my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.picasso', name: 'picasso', version: '2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.2'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: clean, rebuild your project. if it doesn't work then invalidate & restart android studio

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/q/50289355

Comment: @Sayem did that but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.The issue was with the following dependency

```
 implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
```

I changed it to the following

```
  implementation 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
```

And it gave me the required zooming properties