# Firebase core dependency : Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

After including Firebase core dependency in my project

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
```

I am getting this error.

> Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel Message{kind=ERROR,
>   text=Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel, sources=[Unknown
>   source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

I went through a few similar questions but none of them seem to solve my error.

Here is my app level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chandranichatterjee.appname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is my project level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have also included below lines in `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try using latest `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'` https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: try replacing `implementation`  by `api`

Comment: @NileshRathod still getting the same error

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289355/google-material-design-library-error-program-type-already-present-android-suppo

Comment: @NileshRathod already checked that question,but that did not help.

Comment: @Hanzala getting same error after replacing implementation with api

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee for me both **`15.0.2`**  and **`16.0.6`** is working fine with **`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`**

Comment: did you replace all `implementation` with `api`?

Comment: @NileshRathodok,let me try that combination

Comment: @Hanzala yes i did replace all three of them

Comment: @NileshRathod nope,not working.gradle build successfully but when trying to deploy, got same error

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee you are using `firebase-core` for FCM??

Comment: Change _com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1_ to _com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0_ . Then use _implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'_

Comment: @Piyush this didn't work either, however the gradle was built successfully. but when i tried to deploy it,got the same error.Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Comment: Okay.. Is there any support version conflict? Might be you need to exclude support package.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

==>

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

```
Plugin version, Required Gradle version
3.2.0 - 3.2.1 , 4.6+ 
3.3.0 - 3.3.2 , 4.10.1+
3.4.0+        , 5.1.1+
```

2. add `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: I found this solution when I build cocos2d-x project with latest firebase + admob .