# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel in googlesamples/android-play-location

Tags: android

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
>   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate.run(DexMergingTask.kt:316)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTask.taskAction(DexMergingTask.kt:132)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>       at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
>   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
>       at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
>       at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:37)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
>       ... 4 more
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:70)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
>       at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
>       ... 7 more
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
>       ... 10 more
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
>     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>     Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Comment: please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289355/google-material-design-library-error-program-type-already-present-android-suppo.

If enableJetifier doesn't work (which should be) try to remove old support dependencies one by one until detect which one is crashing

Answer (score 1):

add this to gradle.properties file:

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate