# Error : Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I found a problem when I run the 'build> rebuildproject' function but when I run 'build> clean project' the notification of the problem does not exist, this makes me unable to run the application on the emulator and a notification appears stating 'Compilation failed to complete'.
Error notification occurred:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
Message {kind = ERROR, text = Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel, sources = [Unknown source file], tool name = Optional.of (D8)}
```

and

```
: app: transformDexArchieveWithExternalLibsDexMergeForDebug
Execute transform
```

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301692/3518278

Comment: @ViVekH I've tried that and it doesn't work for me. do you have another solution?