# Android Studio 3.5.2 Project Build Problem because of "Multiple dex files define"

Tags: android, android-studio, build, dex

I recently took over work on an Android Studio project whose active development was stopped 18 months ago, in July 2018.

I have been able to build a debug version of the product, but not release. The build is failing on trying to build a new productFlavor that I added today. This is the build error:

```
Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v13/view/inputmethod/InputConnectionCompat$OnCommitContentListener;
```

After syncing with the gradle in the build.,gradle for module App, new build variants are created. When I select the newFlavorDebug I get the above error.  I could go back to the localhost flavor, and could still build localhostDebug, and send it to the emulator to run.  However after going through many questions and answers, one of them suggesting a Build -> Clean Project, now I can not get any flavor to build.

Some things I have already tried from other answers:

- I have added to my app build.gradle, within the android{} block:

```
 dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
```

- I have added within the android defaultConfig

```
        multiDexEnabled true
```

Neither of these have helped.

I have found a lot of variations on this question, with the above answers, but they have not helped in my case.

Here is my configuration and dependency blocks from my app build.gradle:

```
// 2019-11-21 - Added this because of error during build: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v13/view/DragAndDropPermissionsCompat.class
//    This article suggested v4 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult
//    This article suggested v13, but got error "error: package android.support.v13.app does not exist"  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553021/program-type-already-present-android-support-v13-view-draganddroppermissionscom
//    This article, second answer, recommended checking duplicated dependencies in module build.gradle- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553021/program-type-already-present-android-support-v13-view-draganddroppermissionscom
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // This was suggested but didn't work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003114/android-build-fails-over-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files-define
    // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: 'android-support-*.jar')

    //    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.+'
//    compile 'cards.pay:paycardsrecognizer:1.0.0'
    compile 'cards.pay:paycardsrecognizer:1.1.0'
    compile files('src/libs/mint-5.2.2.jar')
    compile 'com.pddstudio:urlshortener:1.0.2'
    compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.14.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.7.2'
    compile 'com.github.twinkle942910:monthyearpicker:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.polok.routedrawer:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
    compile 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
    implementation 'br.com.moip:credit-card-validator:0.0.6'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:3.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
    compile 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'
//    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Note that:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

is getting a warning that some things are asking for version 27.1.1, 26.1.0, and 25.3.1.

I have used this command from Android Studio terminal to see a dependency list:

```
./gradlew -q :app:dependencies
```

It seems that https://github.com/polok/RouteDrawer is the source of dependency to 26.1.0, but it is a code base with no updates for the last 5 years:

```
+--- com.github.polok.routedrawer:library:1.0.0
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3 -> 2.8.1
|    +--- com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.6
|    |    \--- com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:0.20.6
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0 -> 2.5.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0 -> 1.9.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11 -> 12.0.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0

(lines deleted)

|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:12.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:12.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0
|    |    |    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-license:12.0.0
```

And lots of warnings that compile is deprecated and needs to be replaced with implementation.

It is task 5/5 that is failing:

```
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDemo_webmillDebug   1 s 996 ms
  Execute task action 1/5 for :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDemo_webmillDebug 
  Execute task action 2/5 for :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDemo_webmillDebug 
  Execute task action 3/5 for :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDemo_webmillDebug 
  Execute task action 4/5 for :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDemo_webmillDebug 1 ms
  Execute task action 5/5 for :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDemo_webmillDebug 1 s 945 ms
```

Here is an example of the error I get on task action 5.5:

Error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDemo_webmillDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeMultidex(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:266)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:133)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:121)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:72)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v13/view/inputmethod/InputConnectionCompat$OnCommitContentListener;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
    ... 6 more
```

So I have been working through the dependency list, and eliminated the warnings on com.android.support.appcompat-v7, but now there is a warning on mediarouter-v7.   Here is my latest complete build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    flavorDimensions "default"

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.somedev.demoApp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // 2019/11/21 - trying to build a release build threw a lint warning, where lint suggested adding this
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    // This did not solve": Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v13/view/DragStartHelper$OnDragStartListener;
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }


    flavorDimensions "server"
    productFlavors {

        // This is the flavor that runs on MacBook with PHPStorm and Docker
        localhost {
            dimension "server"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"http://192.168.1.117:8081/api/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'USER_PROFILE_URL', '"http://192.168.1.117:8081/admin/file/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'WEB_PORT', '"1738"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'COUNTRY_CODE', '"+1"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'flag', '"us"'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'isDevelopment', 'false'
        }

        // This is the version to run against online server
        newFlavor {
            dimension "server"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"http://demo.mywww.com/api/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'USER_PROFILE_URL', '"http://demo.mywww.com/admin/file/"'
            buildConfigField 'int', 'WEB_PORT', '80'   // Doesnt seem to be used...
            buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_URl', '"72.28.24.98"'   // This seems to have to be IP address of server in BASE_URL
            buildConfigField 'String', 'flag', '"us"'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'isDevelopment', 'false'
        }

    }

}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "http://pay.cards/maven" }
    }
}

// 2019-11-21 - Added this because of error during build: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v13/view/DragAndDropPermissionsCompat.class
//    This article suggested v4 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult
//    This article suggested v13, but got error "error: package android.support.v13.app does not exist"  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553021/program-type-already-present-android-support-v13-view-draganddroppermissionscom
//    This article, second answer, recommended checking duplicated dependencies in module build.gradle- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553021/program-type-already-present-android-support-v13-view-draganddroppermissionscom
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // This was suggested but didn't work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003114/android-build-fails-over-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files-define
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: 'android-support-*.jar')

    //    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.+'
//    compile 'cards.pay:paycardsrecognizer:1.0.0'
    implementation 'cards.pay:paycardsrecognizer:1.1.0'
    implementation files('src/libs/mint-5.2.2.jar')
    implementation 'com.pddstudio:urlshortener:1.0.2'
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.7.2'
    implementation 'com.github.twinkle942910:monthyearpicker:0.0.1'


    implementation ('com.github.polok.routedrawer:library:1.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'mediarouter-v7'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation ('com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2') {
        // exclude module: 'mediarouter-v7'
    }

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
    implementation 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
    implementation 'br.com.moip:credit-card-validator:0.0.6'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:3.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
    implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
    implementation 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'
//    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Articles that do not solve the problem I am having:

- [Android Studio gradle error: multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851103/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define)

  - preDexLibraries option added, didn't help
  - clean build didn't help (in fact, doing this stopped a flavor from building that used to build before the clean in what I received from previous developers)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

Add this block of code in your **build.gradle** file

```
dexOptions {
preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Then **clean** and **rebuild** your project.

Comment: The project has two build.gradle files: One at the project level, and one under the directory app.  The one at the project level gets error when I try to add this. The one under app already has this within the android{} block. Build -> Clean Project, followed by Build -> Rebuild Project  still fails with the same errors shown above.

Comment: May be there's same library with different versions in your gradle file

Comment: Ok, do you have any suggestions of how to look into the project to figure that out? I have figured out how to get gradle to show me dependencies, (as mentioned above), and that has helped me eliminate a couple of warnings about different versions, but same method doesn't seem to be eliminating others.